# How to access a parent variable from a function

Tags: fortran

I have a `pureComp_t` derived type with components `Tc` and `alpha`. `alpha` is of the `alpha_t` derived type. I want the procedure `value`, defined in the `alpha_t` derived type, to be able to access the component `Tc` for some extra calculations.

```
module alpha_m

    type :: alpha_t
        contains
            procedure :: value
    end type

    type pureComp_t
        real(8) :: Tc
        type(alpha_t) :: alpha
    end type

contains

    function value(this,T)
    implicit none

        class(alpha_t) :: this
        real(8) :: T
        real(8) :: value

        value = T / this%Tc

    end function

end module

program regression_alpha

    use alpha_m
    implicit none

    type(pureComp_t) :: pureComp

    pureComp%Tc = 620.d0
    write(*,*)pureComp%alpha%value(610.d0)

end program
```

Right now, I try getting variable `Tc` by writing `this%Tc` but the `this` argument of the function obviously refers to the `alpha_t` derived type and not the the `purecomp_t` derived type.

What modifications could I make to get access to variable `Tc` with a minimum of modifications to the code?

Comment: Where do all the people learn the bad `real(8)` habbit? There must be some influential source of this somewhere.

Comment: It is a school teaching habit. Is there any reason this way of writting should be banned ?

Comment: Banned?  No. Frowned upon? Yes. It does not mean 8-bytes, it does not mean double precision, certain compilers will refuse to compile it (at least by default). Teaching it to newbies is especially harmful. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201703011100570236545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a note on terminology: "parent" in relation to derived types is generally understood in the manner of type extension rather than contents.  That is, in

```
type a
  type(b) x
end type a
```

one wouldn't normally use "parent" to describe the relationship between (an instance of) `a` and its component `x`.

With that said, let's move on to the real question.  Consider the module

```
module m
  type inner
   contains
    procedure :: inner=>inner_value
  end type inner

  type outer
    type(inner) x
    real :: y=1.
  end type outer

 contains

   real function inner_value(this)
     type(inner), intent(in) :: this
     inner_value = ...
   end function

end module m
```

Consider that in our program we want

```
use m
type(outer) a
print *, a%x%value()
end
```

and things so that `inner_value` has access to the components of `a`.  Just to confirm that that makes no sense, what about the program

```
use m
type(inner) b
print *, b%value()   ! There's nothing containing b...
end
```

Now, having spent a lot of lines just restating the question, it's time to look for a solution.

The brief answer is: if we want access to a value that isn't a component of the type that's the passed dummy argument of the type-bound procedure, then we have to get it in scope of that procedure somehow.  How can we do that?

In terms of least modification, perhaps in the module

```
real function inner_value(this, outer_x)
  type(inner), intent(in) :: this
  real, intent(in) :: outer_y
  inner_value = ...
end function
```

so that in the program

```
print *, a%x%value(a%y)
```

Now, that could get tedious and error-prone.  How about having

```
print *, a%value_of_inner()
```

for `value_of_inner()` appropriately doing things of interest.

Alternatively, if the component `alpha_t` never makes sense to be considered outside the context of "being contained within `pureComp_t`" one could consider using type extension.

I won't flesh out the details of these last two approaches.  Or the following, as it's potentially a little horrible.

Consider the `inner` declaration

```
type inner
  type(outer), pointer :: container=>null()
end type inner
```

Then `container` need simply (and correctly...) be associated with the relevant instance of the `outer` type and reference like

```
real function inner_value(this)
  type(inner), intent(in) :: this
  inner_value = this%container%y
end function
```

That's going to require a fair amount of extra "safety" and "setup" code bolting on.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Your recommandation about using `print *, a%value_of_inner()` has my preference has it will force me to crunch variables and methods into more logical structures, making the code easier to understand.